# Views Page Showing Root Title in Window (not views title + root title)

Tags: views, 7

My views page title is set to "The Title" but my window title shows as "Website" rather than "The Title | Website". This is only for my views. Any ideas what would cause this? I have a few other modules installed but not Page Title, that's disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The title for a view does not show up in window title.   The Window's title is determined by the browser, independent of Drupal. The view title is used as the title before the body of your content in the content display area of the window provided you have configured the view to display the title.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that bit of information, I didn't know this. Do you know of a way to force this to display what I want?